# Xamarin ios google maps blank screen for 10 seconds

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9

I am using google maps in my Xamarin Ios project. When user login to system he gets 10 seconds of blank map screen. After that time mp is loaded and all good.  Issues is not reproduced all the time. Here screen of issue

[image: blank maps screen]

What can cause such issue? Can drawing of lines on map cause such issue?

Comment: Isn't that a normal behaviour ? I imagine the data has to be loaded first

Comment: map should be shown very quickly and data should be drawn later